# R - how to avoid to screw up existing installed packages when installing a new one

Tags: r

I have a high level R question but given the incredible frustration I feel this morning, I thought perhaps to ask and learn from expert people here.
I have R 3.6.0 and spent some time in the past installing different packages (i.e. dplyr, ggplot2, lubricate, and other statistics related packages).
Today I had the bad idea to install the packages mentioned on this post https://appsilon.com/r-logistic-regression/#introduction and as soon as I run (from RStudio)

```
install.packages("caTools") # or perhaps 'caret'
```

That uninstalled existing packages like dplyr, ggplot and all of a sudden nothing works anymore. I get a ton of incompatibility messages, RStudio now tells me it cannot find rLang, and so on.

So my question is: what did I do wrong? In R (if my basic understanding is correct) we cannot build the equivalent of python virtual environments.
How can I avoid to bump into this problem again in the future?
I basically found myself delete completely R from my machine and re-installing everything from scratch.
Thanks for the help

Comment: It's `install.packages`, not libraries.

Comment: There must be more to this. `install.libraries()` does not exist (did you mean `install.packages()`?). Installing caTools (or any other package on CRAN) does not remove any other previously installed packages. I would suggest a fresh reinstall (besides, your version of R is outdated).

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to install.packages(). I don't know what else I could do to prevent this from happening again. Is there a way to say "install version of package X that is compatible with R version 3.6.0"?

Comment: I'd consider updating to the newest version of R and keeping all packages updated. Because the CRAN is highly curated there isn't that much of a need for virtual environments like you'd find in Python, though you can use RStudio via Anaconda if you prefer (I've never used it).